# Issue with kivy Clock updating label

Tags: python, label, kivy, clock

I'm making a label that should update every second or so. I tried making it with the clock schedule but it doesn't seem to work. The weird is if I use a button to call the same function it works fine.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import  StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock


class FirstLayout(BoxLayout):
    r = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FirstLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.change = self.ids.temp_label

    def my_callback(self, *args):
        self.r += 1
        print self.r
        t = str(self.r)
        self.change.text = t


class TryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(FirstLayout().my_callback, 1)
        return FirstLayout()


app = TryApp()
app.run()
```

the .kv file:

```
<FirstLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: temp_label
        text: 'something'
    Button:
        on_press: root.my_callback()
```

When I run the code I get the prints showing that the function is running but the label doesn't update. Anything wrong with my logic there?

Thank you in advance.

PS: I know there are several questions about this here, sadly those I found were replied with answers about using the Clock which I already do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the callback is for an **instance that you don't use**:

```
def build(self):
    Clock.schedule_interval(FirstLayout().my_callback, 1) #<--- FirstLayout created and never used
    return FirstLayout() #this one will be used :(
```

Instead, You need to call the method of the FirstLayout that you **are using**

```
def build(self):
    first_layout = FirstLayout() # "There should be one ..." :)
    Clock.schedule_interval(first_layout.my_callback, 1)
    return first_layout
```

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you very much. I guess I still have a lot to learn about python.